# Mysql table not updating

Tags: php, mysqli

I've copied code from another topic on stackoverflow, but it isn't working here.. Searched on the internet but couldn't find anything about this simple thing, the query is not working.

I want to update a table.

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="klas_bewerken.php">
  <label>Old</label>  <input name="old" type="text" id="textfield" />
  <label>New</label>  <input name="new" type="text" id="textfield" />
<input type="submit" value="Change now" />
</form>
```

Klas_bewerken.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "sms");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$old = $_POST['old'];
$new = $_POST['new'];

echo "Old: $old";
echo "<br /> New: $new";

mysqli_query("UPDATE klas SET klas_id='$new' WHERE klas_id='$old'");

ECHO "<br /><br />Updated.";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Code looks fine to me.. does anyone see the mistake? The table is not updating.

thanks

**edit**

So, more explanation: the table klas has just 1 column: klas_id. There's a row: A3D. I'd like to change that into A3C, so I fill in 'A3D' in old and 'A3C' in new.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: yep, I know, but it's not an 'open' script.. No hackers allowed :)

Comment: @cristi_b The table is not updating

Comment: please show the table definition. Is klas_id auto-increment? What values should be inserted

Comment: You could print the number of rows before update: "select count(*) from klas where klas_id='$old'"
To cover all cases, you could check if your browsers cache is turned off.

Comment: @juergend klas_id is varchar(10), latin1_swedish_ci. No auto-increment. Check main post for more explanation

Comment: @Jellevdschoot Can you please specify what error are you getting?

Comment: @BhavikShah I'm not getting any error, it's just that the table won't update..

Comment: @Jellevdschoot Why dont you try to fire the same query on console so that if there is an error in query, you can find it. If you dont get any error when you execute the query on console then you can firmly focus on other factors.

Comment: @BhavikShah when I insert this into the console, it works:    UPDATE `klas` SET `klas_id`="A3C" WHERE `klas_id`="A3D";. But when I (could be my fault?) change this to a php version, it isn't working..

Comment: Even this code isn't working: mysqli_query("UPDATE klas SET klas_id='A3C' WHERE klas_id='A3D'");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing here Procedural and OO style.You can't mix those two,the code should look something like this(not tested but should work)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "sms");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$old = $_POST['old'];
$new = $_POST['new'];

echo "Old: $old";
echo "<br /> New: $new";

$mysqli->query("UPDATE klas SET klas_id='$new' WHERE klas_id='$old'");

ECHO "<br /><br />Updated.";
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Also be sure to escape those chars if you intend it for wider use

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Could you tell me how to 'escape those chars'?  I'd love to make this script more safe, but I don't know where to start haha :). Thanks again!

Comment: No problem,well i use addslashes for it.It adds slashes which in php and mysql are treated like ignore signs \' would mean to print it also instead of ending statement.Also check for existence of [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) i all ways turn it off by ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following after you create your connection and you get your POST variables:

```
$update = "UPDATE klas SET klas_id='".$new."' WHERE klas_id='".$old."'";
if ($run = $mysqli->query($update)) {
    echo 'Success';
    $run->free();
    $mysqli->close();
} else {
    echo 'Error Updating Content';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, when I use this code, it echo's Error Inserting Content.. @rest, when I insert the query I'm using directly into phpmyadmin SQL, I'm getting an error aswell..

Comment: It is a problem with your update statement then. Verify that `klas_id='***'` is actually valid to use. The answer I posted is 100% functional on my end.

Comment: Strange, I've got the update query from the W3 website.. Pff, does anyone has a working script for editing a mysql table with html forms? I've searched for hours, but nothing is working fine. Just a simple script where the table is showed, with an link to a field where you can insert a new value.. That's what I'd like to make here, but I'm stuck already haha..

Answer (score 0):

your code cant update by itself when nothing passed to `POST` , and your sql is updating by POST variables.
try first check if submitted like bellow .

and u must escape ur variables for preventing sql injections.

also you are making `mysql` when u close connection instead it must be `mysqli`

```
      <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "sms");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$old = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['old']);
$new = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['new']);

echo "Old: ". $old;
echo "<br /> New: " .$new;

$mysqli->query("UPDATE klas SET klas_id='".$new."' WHERE klas_id='".$old."'");
mysqli_close($mysqli); }
 ECHO "<br /><br />Updated.";
?>
```

Comment: try this code , it will help u, if u get some error please post it

Comment: I've tried it, but the table won't update. I've copied some parts into the working code, but it makes them 'un-working'. This part, for example:  $old = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['old']); is breaking the thing. When I just insert $old = $_POST['old'];, it IS working.. Any ideas?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is for prevent sql injection only , to escape your variables. u can remove it if u want your website to be injected by worm sqls

Comment: Haha, ofcourse I don't want that, but the code isn't working with that piece of code.. Do you know why?

Comment: try this `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Answer (score -2):

try running your query as this

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE klas SET klas_id='".$new."' WHERE klas_id='".$old."'");
```

i believe is was updating "$old" as "$new" but no "$old" values ever existed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried the code, but the table won't update. What do you mean? I've got a table with A3D as klas_id. So, in old I fill in 'A3D' and in new I fill in 'A3B'. It should update then, right?

Comment: of course, or you can alter your code to simply echo the query and then copy paste it into phpmyadmin and test it there ...

Comment: @cristi_b Why do you believe that $old never existed?

Comment: maybe I didn't express myself clearly but what I meant to say is that the query looked like this UPDATE klas SET klas_id='$new' WHERE klas_id = '$old' , notice that $new and $old in this case are actually strings, not variables

Comment: They're not strings, because the whole query is wrapped in double quotes, for example `echo "$old"` will output the value of `$old` not actual string

Comment: @cristi_b It looks to me that they are variables with string values which is exactly what they should be. I'll notify the authorities, but I still don't see anything suspicious.

Comment: this is how I'd solve this problem, if you have a better solution, go ahead and post a better answer